# Servo control arduino

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, jointstate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to control a servo attached to arduino by subscribing to /joint_states topic so that when the change the slider position the servo moves accordingly.
I tried with the following code but the servo doesn't change its position when i change the slider position on rviz.
The led on Arduino blinks as written in the callback function but the servo isn't moving.

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
  #include "Arduino.h"
#else
  #include <WProgram.h>
#endif

#include <Servo.h> 
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;
Servo servo;

double ang=0;

void servo_cb( const sensor_msgs::JointState& cmd_msg){
  ang=radiansToDegrees(cmd_msg.position[0]);
  servo.write(ang); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));  //toggle led  
}


ros::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::JointState> sub("joint_states", servo_cb);

void setup(){
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
  
  servo.attach(9); //attach it to pin 9
}

void loop(){
  nh.spinOnce();
}

double radiansToDegrees(float position_radians)
{

  position_radians = position_radians + 1.6;

  return position_radians * 57.2958;

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269960/servo-control-arduino/) by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-15**:
@Yogi_4 may you help me for this ?

**Comment by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on 2018-01-16**:
What is the issue? @lagankapoor

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-18**:
I have one Lynxmotion Arm and i want to use that with MoveIt , if any more detail needed please visit my new question that i post today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it solved issue was with baud rate

---

Originally posted by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) with karma: 38 on 2017-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0